# What figure is traced here?

Tags: geometry

You have triangle $ABC$. Suppose $BC$, which is of fixed length, lies on the $x$-axis, and $\alpha$, on vertex $A$, is an angle with a fixed value, while $\beta,\gamma$ are variable.

Since $\gamma=\pi-\beta-\alpha$, what figure (and its equation) is traced by $A$ while $\beta$ varies from $0<\beta<\pi-\alpha$?

I have a feeling that this is an ellipse, or half of an ellipse since you can't have $\beta,\gamma=\pi$, OR it could be entirely different. I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an arc of a circle: [Inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).